# Failed to convert value of type String on Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Iam trying to make the Admin Login but my login activity keep giving me error, there is 2 ways to login for admin they would click on another textview to change some settings then login...login works fine for users, but to admin it keeps giving me errors..

my login Activity:

```
private TextView register;
private Button login;
private TextInputLayout phoneNum, inputPassword;
private ProgressDialog loadingDialog;
private TextView adminLink, notAdminLink, title;

private String parentDbName = "Users";
private CheckBox rememberMe;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

    loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    title = findViewById(R.id.title);

    //Button
    register = findViewById(R.id.register);
    login = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    //EditText
    phoneNum = findViewById(R.id.login_phone_num);
    inputPassword = findViewById(R.id.login_passBox);

    //Checkbox
    rememberMe = findViewById(R.id.remember_me_chk);

    //admin
    adminLink = findViewById(R.id.admin_link);
    notAdminLink = findViewById(R.id.not_admin);

    
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });

    //CheckBox EVERY time app start
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("checkBox", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String checkBox = preferences.getString("remember", "");

    if (checkBox.equals("true")) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    } else if (checkBox.equals("false")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Sign In.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LoginUser();
        }
    });

    // Automatically Login
    rememberMe.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (compoundButton.isChecked()) {
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("checkBox", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("remember", "true");
                editor.apply();

            } else if (!compoundButton.isChecked()){
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("checkBox", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("remember", "false");
                editor.apply();
            }
        }
    });


    //Admins
    adminLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            login.setText(R.string.Admin_login);
            title.setText(R.string.admin_panel_title);
            rememberMe.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            adminLink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            notAdminLink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            parentDbName = "Admins";
        }
    });

    notAdminLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            login.setText(R.string.login);
            title.setText(R.string.login);
            rememberMe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            adminLink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            notAdminLink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            parentDbName = "Users";
        }
    });
}

private void LoginUser() {
    String phone = phoneNum.getEditText().getText().toString();
    String pass = inputPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter Your PhoneNum.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }  else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter Your Password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        loadingDialog.setTitle("Login Your Account...");
        loadingDialog.setMessage("Connecting...");
        // prevent it from disappearing when clicked outside
        loadingDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        loadingDialog.show();

        AccessAccount(phone,pass);
    }
}
private void AccessAccount(String phone, String pass) {
    final DatabaseReference rootRef;
    rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.child(parentDbName).child(phone).exists()) {
                Users userData = snapshot.child(parentDbName).child(phone).getValue(Users.class);
                if (userData.getPhone().equals(phone)) {
                    if (userData.getPassword().equals(pass)) {
                        if (parentDbName.equals("Admins")) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Admin: " + userData.getName() + "\nWish You have a good Day", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingDialog.dismiss();

                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminCategoryActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        } else if (parentDbName.equals("Users")) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Welcome Back " + userData.getName() + " Wish You have a good Day", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingDialog.dismiss();

                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Password is Incorrect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "This phone Number doesn't Exist.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Error Message :
[image]

Comment: Users phone field is String but in firebase, I guess you are storing phone as Long . Correct me If I am wrong. Please include Users class as well as Firebase data for clarification

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data) and indicate the exact data you want to get. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing a field as long in Firebase and Parsing that Field as String in app side.Most Probably that field is phone

Comment: so how to store it as a string in firebase

Comment: Your Users Model datatype for phone should be String not long

Answer (score 0):

*Users userData = snapshot.child(parentDbName).child(phone).getValue(Users.class);

*In this line you are passing textInputLayout as child that's the error

*Check the child name in your firebase database